# How to receive files in the cakephp 3 that are passed through an angular http post method?

Tags: angular, cakephp-3.4

iam sending the file through http post method in angular 13
before sending file iam appending file and file.name to formData() and sending it.
Now how to receive that file in the backend of cakephp 3.0

Comment: Should we all assume there is no documentation for cakephp that would describe how to do this?

Comment: i dont know whether it is there in documentation of cakephp or not https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/index.html

Comment: Just search for **upload**, it is very much documented: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#file-uploads